# Setting up HTTPS for AWS Lightsail backend instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ssl, https, amazon-lightsail

I have a web-page hosted in S3 bucket, and it is setup for HTTPS.

My back-end runs on an AWS Lightsail instance with a static IP address that my front-end makes requests to to get JSON data. The server is a Python Flask server that is running within a Docker container.

When I run `docker run -p 443:MY_PORT ...` (port **443** is Lightsail's HTTPS port) I cannot get my front-end to communicate with the server. Instead I get this error:

> spread.js:25 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.bible-it.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint ... This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

There are no problems, if I run my docker command through port 80.

**What is the best way to setup HTTPS for my Lightsail instance?**

Also if my setup of

FRONTEND: s3 Bucket

BACKEND: Lightsail > Ubuntu > Docker > Python Flask

is a bad setup  please let me know. I am self taught and would love some guidance. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error message says, your server does not serve the content properly over HTTPS. This could have several reasons:

- Your requests are redirected to HTTP. Make sure that your server does not do that.
- Your Lightsail instance does not allow HTTPS connections. In this case you have to [update your instance's firewall](https://github.com/ElisabethStrunk/LinuxServerConfiguration/blob/master/set_up_a_TLS-SSL_certificate.md#configure-your-firewall).
- Your TLS/SSL certificate is not set up properly. In this case you can use e.g. [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) and follow their documentation for a proper setup.

One last tip:

If I understand you correctly, you are running your application on the development server. This is the case, if you run your Flask application with

```
from Flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.run()
```

In general, you should not use the development server in production.

> It is not designed to be particularly efficient, stable, or secure. It
>   does not support all the possible features of a HTTP server.

You can read more about this in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982807/are-a-wsgi-server-and-http-server-required-to-serve-a-flask-app/38982989#38982989).

Comment: Thank you I will try your suggestions, the update to firewall looks promising. I will update shortly.

Comment: Quick question. In the /var/www/item_catalog/item_catalog.wsgi

the commands:


```import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/item_catalog/item_catalog")
from app import app as application```

is the last line saying ** from the directory app import the flask object app as application***?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Are you deploying your app with WSGI now?

Comment: Thank you I was able to get everything working properly.  This was an amazing resource, I will keep this, I really learn alot.

Comment: So glad to hear that my notes were helpful to you :)